# Can I claim property tax & interest deduction if I pay the mortgage on my mother-in-law's house?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, real-estate, tax-deduction

I currently pay mortgage (taxes, interest) on my mother-in-law's house. The house is under her name but we live in it. Can I use the interest and taxes as deductions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't own the property, so no.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum ownership requirement just that you be one of the owners. If you expect this arrangement to continue for a while, you might suggest she sell you a 1% ownership of the property. The mortgage and taxes as an itemized deduction might make this well worth it.

Comment: I am in the same situation as Mitch, except that I am paying mortgage on my mother's house and my name (and my brother's) is on the title of the house.  It is my understanding we need 1098 to itemize the deduction, so how do I get my 1098?